# Sending a simple email using java

Tags: java, email, smtp

```
public class emailfromgmail {
     String from = "sender@gmail.com";
     String to = "recipient@gmail.com";
     String host="localhost";

     //get the session object

     Properties p = System.getProperties();
     p.setProperty("mail.smtp.host", host);
     Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(p);
}
```

Actually I want to tell you that I didn't complete the code because it start giving me error at the 6th line which is `p.setProperty("mail.smtp.host",host)`.
It says `package p does not exist <identifier> expected illegal start of type`. I don't know what is wrong with this.

Comment: You need to write your email sending code within a method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT**

In respone to OP's comment:

You are missing a method declared around the operations you are performing. For the example OP linked to, the operations were in the `Main` method:

```
public class emailfromgmail {

  public static void main(String[] args){//This is the method declaration
```

Make sure to then close the method after your operations with a `}` before the class closing `}`

**Original answer:**

The line:

`p.setProperty("mail.smtp.host", host);`

Shouldn't be in the class section. It needs to go either in a method or the constructor. What you should do is something like this:

```
public class emailfromgmail {

    String from, to, host;
    //etc.

    public emailfromgmail(String from, String to, String host){ //any other parameters as well
        this.from = from;
        this.to = to;
        this.host = host;
        //etc..

    }
```

Then pass the parameters to that constructor like:

```
emailfromgmail email = new emailfromgmail("palaksharma786@gmail.com","vineetsharma123786@gmail.com","localhost");
```

Then use a method to do the operations like setting up the properties and sending etc:

```
public void send(){
    Properties p = System.getProperties();
    p.setProperty("mail.smtp.host",host);
    //etc..

}
```

Comment: Sir i do not understand why I have to do this , actually I'm referring to this site https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_sending_email.htm and it didn't use a method or constructor.

Comment: In the example you are looking at, he IS using a method. The method is the "Main" method, which is opened by the line " public static void main(String [] args) {    "